# Javascript Regex, replace just once

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is one example of what I need.

If I have some text like this one:

```
var string = "This is some test string for some my test.";
```

Then I have Regex like this one:

```
var patern = new RegExp("\\bsome\\b", 'gi');
```

and then line for replace:

```
var new_string = string.replace(patern,"replace_string");
```

This line above will replace all words "some" in string with "replace_string".

```
 new_string = "This is replace_string test string for replace_string my test."
```

What I need is to limit it to replace it just once.
Is that possible, and how?

Comment: Don't supply the "g" flag if you don't want to do a global replace.

Comment: Thanks, In meanwhile I figured it out. I just was to delete question and you commented :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass `'g'` (global) as the second argument in the regex, maybe try something like `str.replace(pattern);` or `str.replace(pattern, 'i');` to keep ignoring case.

Answer (score 0):

```
'This is some test string for some my test.'.replace(/\bsome\b/, 'replace_string'); 
// => "This is replace_string test string for some my test."
```